# Do we really need this [framework]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I'm questioning the usefulness of the [framework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framework) tag. There are only 20 questions at the moment and they don't appear to have much in common. Seems like some kind of catch all tag to me. Should we burn it?

Comment: *In most cases the tag for a specific framework should be used instead of this tag.* this indicates that it is intended to be used when *using* frameworks, not when writing them (like [tag:library]). Does indeed seem to be a "catch all" tag.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is a difference between a framework and a library.

Comment: [One person](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32241/node-js-review-core-class-of-a-javascript-framework-for-spas) did use it to tag a framework they were writing, is it worth keeping on that one question?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan that's a fair point, but if it stays, we need to clarify what the tag is for and clean it up. I'm open to proposals other than burnination. If I was 100% sure it needed to go, I would have just removed it. I'm not. Hence the meta.

Comment: @RubberDuck I edited the tag excerpt to specify not to use it just for framework usage and use specific framework's tag in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Burninate

From the tag wiki excerpt:

> *"In most cases the tag for a specific framework should be used instead of this tag."*

If this tag is only supposed to be used to indicate that you're **using** a framework, it really doesn't serve a purpose, since we already have tags like [.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net). Let's burninate it.

Answer (score 2):

Not every framework needs it's own tag. If a specific tag is available, use that. If not, use [framework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framework). It explicitly states there is no vanilla situation, which is valuable.